# Powershell scripting "hostname" output only 3 letters either first or last 3 letters

Tags: powershell

Can someone help me get my computername via PowerShell, with either, only the first 3 letters, or just the last 3 letters.

I can do it with `cmd.exe`, using `%computername:~0,3%` and `%computername:~-3%` respectively.

I tried `hostname:~0,3` but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First 3 letters:

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME.substring(0, 3)
```

Last 3 letters:

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME.Substring($env:COMPUTERNAME.Length - 3)
```

You can get the computer name from the environ variables
To manage strings, you can use the .NET method [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-7.0)